# why does ''tput ed'' delete lines, instead of just clearing one line?

Tags: bash, terminfo, tput

i want to rewrite first line but tput is removing all lines instead of first line

im testing this

```bash
cl=$(tput ed)
tput sc
echo 'line1____'
echo 'line2____'
echo 'line3____'
sleep 1
tput rc
echo "abc$cl"
echo ''
echo ''
sleep 1
```

when done it should look like

```
abc
line2____
line3____
```

but it is doing

```
abc
            -empty
            -empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `tput el` (clear to end of line) instead of `tput ed` (clear to end of screen):

```
cl=$(tput el)
```

From the man pages for `terminfo`:

```
     Variable            Cap-      TCap       Description
      String             name      Code

clr_eol                  el        ce     clear to end of line (P)
                         ^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

clr_eos                  ed        cd     clear to end of screen (P*)
                         ^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I make this one change (`cl=$(tput el)`) to your code it now generates:

```
abc
line2____
line3____
```